# Rails+simple_form_for Change common id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form-for

I want to change form common name in rendering side

```
_from.html.haml
..
= f.simple_fields_for Image.new do |form|
      = render 'avatar_fields', f: form
..

_avatar_fields.html.haml
..
     = f.hidden_field :imageable_type
..
```

This is rendering like

```
<input id="product_image_imageable_type" name="product[image][imageable_type]" type="hidden">
```

But i want to render like this

```
<input id="product_logo_attributes_imageable_type" name="product[logo_attributes][imageable_type]" type="hidden">
```

I don't want to edit my '_avatar_fields.html.haml' screen. Because it's common html.

Any suggestion please..?

Answer (score 0):

you can do some thing like

```
...
  = f.hidden_field :imageable_type, input_html: {id: 'product_logo_attributes_imageable_type'}
...
```

I hope that this helps you

Comment: Thanks you for your reply.. This will change only for that input field. But, I want to change id for all fields from images -> logo_attributes. I want to do it dynamically from that simple_form

Comment: have you looked at the https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon gem